# FileNotFoundException with getResources

Tags: java, file-io

I used Class.getResource (String) to retrieve the url of a file, and it works very well, but when I try to 'insatncié a FileReader with the url returned, an exception:**java.io.FileNotFoundException**  is triggered

```
URL bpmnResourceUrl = ConvertXmlToJson.class.getClassLoader().getResource("file.txt");
Reader reader = new FileReader(bpmnResourceUrl.toString());
```

Comment: That exception is thrown because file.txt is not there. On your class loader you do not have that file.

Comment: getResource returns correct url of file.txt, it is possible that it returns a value other than null although the file was not found in the class loader !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Resource in Java is not a File. If the Resource is inside a JAR, for example, you can't access it like a File. You have to explode the JAR first. You may try:

```
Class.getResourceAsStream()
```

to read the content. Here is a short example:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Example.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")));
        String line;
        do {
            line = br.readLine();
            if (line != null) System.out.println(line);
        } while (line != null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't open it as a file, use it as InputStream, in your case, if you want a Reader to get the data then you can use:

```
InputStream is = ConvertXmlToJson.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");

Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
```

When you load a resource from Classpath, such resource can be located inside a jar file, so It's not accesible like a regular file in filesystem, but you can open a Stream to read it, as  the code shows.